# gorm does not add ondelete cascade action in a existing database

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a permanently delete with Unscoped method and I need to trigger ondelete cascade to avoid delete data from the children tables related.

A workaround is to drop manually one by one the foreign keys and recreate it with gorm migration and then it works fine.

Then I am using constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE, and it creates fine the ondelete cascade in postgres database for a new database, but it is not able to alter an existing database created with gorm.

```
type Bugreport struct {
    //gorm.Model
    ID        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index;index:natural_unique_key,unique"`

    FileName             string
    Reporter             string
    UserName             string
    UploadSize           int64
    DateUploaded         string
    DateCreated          string
    SerialNumber         string `gorm:"index:natural_unique_key,unique"`
    HardwareRevision     string
    BuildFingerprint     string `gorm:"index:natural_unique_key,unique"`
    ArgusID              string
    NumberOfBoots        int
    TotalNumberOfCrashes int
    GrafanaDashboardLink string
    ConcatenatedFileLink string
    FilesConcatenated    int
    LogLinesParsed       int
    OriginalFile          bool `gorm:"default:false"`
    Boots                []Boot `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    BootDr               BootDr `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    Crashes              []Crash `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    Memory               Memory `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    IniTime      time.Time `gorm:"type:timestamp;column:iniTime","index:natural_unique_key,unique"`
    EndTime      time.Time `gorm:"type:timestamp;column:endTime"`
    Duration         int `gorm:"index:natural_unique_key,unique"`
    //Encrypt        string
}
```

Thank you